# window.scrollTo() smooth jump not triggered by onclick event

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to have window.scrollTo jump to a class smoothly in vanilla js if it's not triggered by an onclick event of a button?

```
if(i <0) {
  window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector(".site-header- wrapper").offsetTop);
}
```

I have tried putting something together like this, but frankly don't know what I am doing here

```js
if(i <0) {
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var n = 0;
  var int = setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, n);
    n -= 10;
    if (n <= document.querySelector(".site-header-wrapper").offsetTop) clearInterval(int);
  }, 20);
})
}
```

Comment: Didn't you just post an answer "with" an onclick event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how willing you are to omit the smooth scrolling in some browsers, but you could do something like

```
document.querySelector(".site-header-wrapper").scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
});
```

That will scroll smoothly in latest Firefox and Chrome but jump instantly in IE, Edge, and Safari.

It's not quite the same as `scrollTo`, but might be an acceptable substitute. Otherwise, you'll have to manage the animation using JavaScript, e.g. as per the link in the comment.